# Почему не работает вывод категорий?

Tags: php

```
    <?

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('blog');

$count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question_categories`");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question_categories`");
$categorie = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($count);

?>
<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Как выучить php быстрее?" name="question_title">
    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Когда я создавал сайт я столкнулся с такой проблемой..."></textarea>
    <select>
    <?
        for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
        {
            echo("<section>" . $categorie['title'] . "</section>");
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Не работает вывод категорий

Comment: Что говорят логи?

Comment: Ничего, просто нету категорий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что результат запроса `SELECT * FROM question_categories` не пустой. Для подсчета количества строк функцией [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php), не нужно посылать еще один запрос к БД. Данный код

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question_categories`");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question_categories`");
$categorie = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($count);
```

можно заменить на:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question_categories`");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Вывод результата запроса cделайте через цикл [while](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles#while) с использованием [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
while ($categorie = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<section>" . $categorie['title'] . "</section>";
}
```

Данные функции по работе с mysql уже старели и не рекомендуются к использованию. Вместо них используйте функции [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).